# javascript constant and opera browser

Tags: javascript, constants

```
<html>
   <head><title>Using the const Keyword</title>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          const NOON = 12;
          const FREEZING = 32; // Can't change
       </script>
   </head>
  <body bgcolor="silver">
    <big>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write("Fahrenheit temp is " + FREEZING + ".<br />");
      FREEZING =32 + 10;
      NOON = NOON + " noon";
      document.write("Make it warmer " + FREEZING + ".<br />");
      document.write("See you at ", NOON, ".<br />");
    </script>
  </big>
 </body>
</html>
```

Above code is working fine with Firefox, Chrome, Safari but it is not working with opera 12.02. Since I have used keyword 'const' Result should be as follow

Farenheit temp is 32.
Make it warmer 32.
See you at 12.

But opera browser displays

Farenheit temp is 32.
Make it warmer 42.
See you at 12 noon.

What is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong is that `const` isn't officially supported in Opera, that's all. It's been a long time that developer claimed that, but it still lags behind. It's still not part of ECMASCript.

Try this instead:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "NOON", {
    value: 12, writable: false, configurable: false
});
```

This works in Opera. If you intend to support IE<9 too, you should use something a bit different (and less effective):

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "NOON", {
    get: function() {return 12;}
});
```

You still won't be able to change its value, but you'll be able to redefine `NOON` with `Object.defineProperty`.

Answer (score 3):

***[From here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)***

> The current implementation of const is a Mozilla-specific extension
>   and is not part of ECMAScript 5. It is supported in Firefox & Chrome
>   (V8). As of Safari 5.1.7 and Opera 12.00, if you define a variable
>   with const in these browsers, you can still change its value later. It
>   is not supported in Internet Explorer 6-9, or in the preview of
>   Internet Explorer 10. The const keyword currently declares the
>   constant in the function scope (like variables declared with var).

Answer (score 1):

`const` isn't a standard JavaScript keyword. Not all browsers have it. Use `var` instead:

```
var FREEZING = 32;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally browsers support it's now (2017) perfect -> https://caniuse.com/#feat=const